# Use Webpack to include Zurb Foundation via NPM

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, webpack

I'm probably just being dense here, but how can I use Webpack to use npm (package.json) to pull down latest Zurb Foundation and use it in the bundle?

I see examples, for example [here](https://github.com/starterkits/frontend-starterkit-webpack), that demonstrate Zurb and Webpack together, but they always seem to use Bower to get foundation.  I'd like to eliminate Bower from my workflow and use straight npm+webpack (or +gulp if necessary).

Thoughts?

---

I guess maybe all I really need is an example of package.json that pulls in latest Zurb foundation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM + Zurb Foundation + WebPack: Cannot resolve module 'foundation'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297788/npm-zurb-foundation-webpack-cannot-resolve-module-foundation)

Comment: not really, the linked issue is about to load particular js files

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, I wanted to drop bower, so I started with Foundation 6.

There were some tricky parts, but I got it working now and created a boilerplate project: https://github.com/timaschew/r3-foundation-boilerplate

The project uses Redux and React, but you should extract the most important stuff from the [webpack.config](https://github.com/timaschew/r3-foundation-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js) and the [entry point](https://github.com/timaschew/r3-foundation-boilerplate/blob/master/src/containers/app.js#L9-L15)

**Summary of the tricky parts**

- install foundation via `npm i foundation-sites`
- install jquery with npm as well `npm i jquery`
- use a script-loader to load jquery and foundation js files in the global window scope
- configure sass-loader to use sass files and **adjust the CSS Output** like descripted in the docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a duplicate question, but I'm crossposting [my answer to the other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985872/1148030), because people might land here through search and not notice the duplicate link.

---

This is the common place to land from web search with beginner questions related to the technologies mentioned in the question.

Here is my  [Zurb Foundation with SCSS and Webpack Example Project](https://github.com/pelamfi/zurb-foundation-scss-webpack-example).

Feel free to clone it. It is licensed with the Unlicense.

### Background

Although, the module compatibility issues are resolved with recent (> 6.4) versions of the Zurb Foundation, a basic setup may still seem like black magic for a beginner. I think there must be other and probably better examples like mine somewhere, but I just couldn't find them. I'm adding the fruits of my learning journey here in the hopes that it will make somebody's ride a bit less bumpy.